How to make excel detect Products in a Bundle and deduct each of said Products in Inventory?

As shown from the picture, it doesnt deduct the SKU sale from Bundle with the sumif formula
Lets say Bundle A has Product A100, B100 and C100
I have 3 tables:

Bundle table: List out Bundles with whatever product and quantity under that table
Inventory table: List out Products leftover units
Sales Table: Record sales on products and bundles

The aim is to find the closing inventory of each Products. If it is just a normal sale, then I can just use Product Opening Quantity minus SUMIF(Product SKU Range,Product SKU,Quantity) and I will get the closing. But what if there is a Bundle that contains multiple products? How do I make excel detect Bundle A has Product A100, B100 and C100 then deduct it in the inventory of Product A100, B100 and C100?
Hopefully it is understandable
I have tried using Vlookup but it only returns 1 value, i also tried Filter but got no idea how to make the Opening Quantity to minus it. I am at total loss

Post few sample data and then show your desired result.

Can the same product be part of different bundles? And it would make Excel-life easier to not have empty cells in table Bundle info.

Same products will also appear in different bundle
As for those empty cells, i filled it with different the Bundles name

Can you edit your question and add input data as table Markdown and also add expected output? How would you calculate result manually?

In cell G2 the formula is
=SUM(IF($E2=Table3[SKU],OFFSET(Table3[SKU],0,1),0))+SUM(BYROW(Table3[SKU],LAMBDA(x,SUM(IF((x=Table1[Bundle])*(Table1[SKU]=$E2),(Table1[Qty])*OFFSET(x,0,1),0)))))
and then copy down. The values are the total sold for further using.


I think you can remove IF. =($E2 = SalesTable[SKU])*SalesTable[Quantity] for SKU, =BYROW(SalesTable[SKU], LAMBDA(x, SUM((x = BundleTable[Bundle]) * (BundleTable[SKU] = $E2) * BundleTable[Qty] * OFFSET(x, 0, 1)))) for bundle...

Black cat! your method works! thank you so much for the help!
There is this another thing, there is a third column called "Status" on Table 3, it refers to the product being shipped/cancelled/refunded etc. How do i make the formula to only sum it if its "Shipped"?
I tried using the SUMIF and IF function but always return VALUE error.
rachel, I also tried your way but doesnt seems to work for me. Thank you for your help though!

While I'm sure it can be done with a formula and no doubt somebody will come up with it, I think a far better tool to help with it would be Power Query.
To make it happen you have to structure your data a little better changing the Bundle table to something like:

And now it's pretty simple to transform your data and get the final result, this is really just an example code and could be improved but just to show how it can be done:
let
// Load Bundle Table
BundleTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="BundleTable"]}[Content],

// Load Sales Table
SalesTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SalesTable"]}[Content],

// Merge Sales with Bundle
MergedSales = Table.NestedJoin(SalesTable, "SKU", BundleTable, "Bundle", "BundleDetails", JoinKind.LeftOuter),

// Expand Bundle Details
ExpandedSales = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergedSales, "BundleDetails", {"SKU", "Qty"}, {"Bundle_SKU", "Bundle_Qty"}),

// Adjust Quantities
AdjustedSales = Table.TransformColumns(ExpandedSales, {{"Qty", each if _ is null then 1 else _, type number}, {"Bundle_Qty", each if _ is null then 1 else _, type number}}),

// Calculate Total Qty
TotalSales = Table.AddColumn(AdjustedSales, "TotalQty", each [Qty] * [Bundle_Qty]),
AddSalesSKU = Table.AddColumn(TotalSales, "Sales SKU", each if [Bundle_SKU] is null then [SKU] else [Bundle_SKU]),
CleanUp = Table.RemoveColumns(AddSalesSKU,{"SKU", "Qty", "Bundle_SKU", "Bundle_Qty"}),
Group = Table.Group(CleanUp, {"Sales SKU"}, {{"Sales Total", each List.Sum([TotalQty]), type number}})
in
Group


Appreciate your help! but I would prefer formulas whenever possible as I have no idea how to even start on Power Query, it seems quite advance to me.
Thank you so much for the help!
